# When to use partials and when to functions?

Tags: php, laravel

I was just wondering, what is 'better' to do when building an application (Laravel and PHP in my case); including partials in your view or use function to generate the html?

When would you use each? Is there a 'golden rule' to follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On the whole, it's considered to be best practice to keep logic *out* of the view component(s) of your application. A view contains the layout, no logic except for the occassional `if` and loop. Using a function that returns HTML feels wrong in an MVC context. The controller manages the request, and passes the result from the model layer (the actual data) to the view, possibly after some minor formatting.

A function returning a view *might* be used to send a response to ajax calls that require the data to be formatted in a special format (XML for some reason, instead of json). But the use-cases are, IMHO, rather limited.

Basicly, if you find yourself repeating a lot of markup in various view scripts, create a partial and include that. If you have a rather messy loop in your view, consider creating a partial that generates HTML, and use that in your loop body, to keep the files easier to maintain. Defining functions inside a view is right out, and having functions that return the same markup over and over is just weird, and looks messy.
My 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

I use functions for html that needs to be build, like form inputs and such. Partials I use for html that does not change but is required in multiple views, like sidebars.

Comment: What's wrong with `Form::text('fieldName');`? Why use a custom function for that? I'd create a partial to build forms that aren't bound to a model

Comment: I said that I 'use' functions, not where they reside or what they are bound to. For form inputs I just have my own form macro's. So there is nothing wrong with `Form::text()` except that I like a bit more functionality.